# Mysql column not returning correct value

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach

I'm trying to get the number of places left on a course from a specific column. However, the  result is returning *4* which is incorrect. It should be **15**.

Here is the code:

```
$courseID = $_GET['id'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM course_dates WHERE id = '$courseID'");


$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);


foreach ($row as $record) {
    $placesLeft = $record['places'];
}


echo $placesLeft;
```

Is it obvious, am I being a complete noob?

EDIT: var_dump of $row:

```
   array(7) { 
    [0]=> string(1) "2"
    [1]=> string(1) "2"
    [2]=> string(56) "Essential leadership and mangement skills in the new nhs"
    [3]=> string(6) "London"
    [4]=> string(10) "2012-12-15"
    [5]=> string(2) "15"
    [6]=> string(3) "450"
   }
```

Comment: you are looping to get the val and echoing out side the loop !!

Comment: moving echo $placesLeft; to foreach

Answer (score 1):

i believe your id is primary/unique key

so you'll get only one row as result set

so using:

```
$row['places'];
```

is enough don't iterate it again

Comment: This didn't do anything :s

Comment: what do you mean by didnt do anything? no output?

Comment: yup, there was nothing outputted

Comment: did u `print_r()` it??

Comment: print_r does nothing and var_dump = NULL

Comment: If your column is an `int` you could try changing `WHERE id = '$courseID'")` to `WHERE id = $courseID")` @MarkP

Comment: try print_r($row); after the mysql_query

Answer (score 1):

Try this method instead:

Using `$courseID = "1";` and having `1` and `Place ONE` and `Spain` in their respective columns produced:

1
Place ONE
Spain

```
<?php
$DB_HOST = "xxx";
$DB_NAME = "xxx";
$DB_PASS = "xxx";
$DB_USER = "xxx";

$db = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($db->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

// $courseID = $_GET['id'];
$courseID = "1"; // my own test. Column set to (INT)

$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM course_dates WHERE id = '$courseID'");

 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    // my own example columns. Change to suit
    echo $row['id'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['places'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['city'];
}

mysqli_close($db);
```

---

Using `$courseID = "2";` and having `2` and `Place TWO` and `LONDON` in their respective columns produced:

2
Place TWO
London